# why don't we directly call methods on a Content Provider object?

Tags: android

Android development:

I don't understand why we use Content resolver to access Content provider . Instead why don't create an instance of Content Provider and directly call methods on it ?

Comment: because you can use a content provider from a different application

Answer (score 1):

Technically you could do this if ContentResolver would be built differently by android.
But the reason to this it's not technical, it's [arcitcherual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_architecture).

> content providers are primarily intended to be used by other
>   applications, which access the provider using a provider client objects

When client application reaches other application data - for example Whatsapp automatically add your contacts via the contact application `ContentProvider`  they don't, and don't need to, care where the `ContentResolver` gathered the data from (e.g local SQlite or maybe a web server).
If one app would directly reaches other app's data many API's would be "broken" over version updates.

Great guide on how the implementation actually happens in the code [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/content-resolvers-and-content-providers.html).

Comment: do you want to say that the Content resolver provides a layer of abstraction above the underlying data source?

Comment: @KishanKumar you cannot create a `ContentProvider` object directly since it can be defined in different application, thats why you need a `ContentResolver`

Comment: Exactly! This is the purpose of this "weird" implementation.

Comment: @KishanKumar Here there is a great example of this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm